# why back button not showing center in toolbar?

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

i am using collapsing toolbar and i am trying to show back button it's it's not showing in `center_vertical` in `toolbar`.

[image: output] that i am getting

Does anyone know why i am getting this output?

**Style**

```
<style name="AppThemeNoActionBarNotch" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#1A000000</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>
</style>
```

I am using this style because i want to show image preview also in `status bar`.

**layout file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".activity.PerformarEventActivity">
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
android:id="@+id/appbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="@dimen/_200sdp"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
    android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:contentScrim="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="@dimen/_64sdp"
    app:expandedTitleMarginStart="@dimen/_48sdp"
    app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgperformarbg"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:background="@drawable/publiek"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="@drawable/gradient"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
        app:titleTextColor="@color/white" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main_sub" />  //RECYCLERVIEW LAYOUT


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

this is my **code**

```
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle(performer_name);
    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_arrow_back_black_24dp);
```

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: any reason you're not just using `.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);`?

Comment: getting same output on setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true) this

Comment: check my updated question

Comment: could you post here entire layout

Comment: check my updated question

Comment: @KeyurPatel what if remove all android:fitsSystemWindows="true" in this layout file?

Comment: getting same output

Comment: Just wonder is the back button is the button in your drawable ? Your drawable named is R.drawable.ic_arrow_back_black_24dp, but the color is white.

Comment: no, it is a vector image picked from vector asset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after removing `fitsSystemWindows="true"` from the style and putting `fitsSystemWindows="true"` to all of the tags, it worked.

Answer (score 3):

*Toolbar supports a more focused feature set than ActionBar. From start to end, a toolbar may contain a combination of the following optional elements:
A navigation button. This may be an Up arrow, navigation menu toggle, close, collapse, done or another glyph of the app's choosing. This button should always be used to access other navigational destinations within the container of the Toolbar and its signified content or otherwise leave the current context signified by the Toolbar. The navigation button is vertically aligned within the Toolbar's minimum height, if set.*

So if you set minHeight attribute the same as your toolbar height (layout_height ), the back arrow will be centered vertically.

More clarification in [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com)

Comment: i have to set toolbar minimum height?

Comment: but which attribute that i have to set minimum height? is it collapsing toolbar or what?

Comment: The navigationButton. ie, the back arrow

Comment: but i am using          toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_arrow_back_black_24dp);
for showing back button how can i set minimum height in this?

Answer (score 0):

set minHeight attribute the same as your toolbar height (layout_height ), the back arrow will be centered vertically.